# Can't seem to get my table to hide back or slide down properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Been trying to get my slideDown effect working and hide but somehow it does not work. Basically my user searches for a record and then it will show the result. There will be a button at the top-right of the search to hide the table or show the table again through a slidedown effect.

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="toggling" id="togglething"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
    <div id="scrolling">
    <!--<div id="loading"></div>-->
    <table id="results" class="table1" cellspacing=10px>
        <thead>
            <tr class = "spacing">
                <th class='headers'>Index No</th>
                <th class='headers'>SAM ID</th>
                <th class='headers'>Item Description</th>
                <th class='headers'>Type</th>
                <th class='headers'>Inventory Status</th>
                <th class='headers'>Issued QTY</th>
                <th class='headers'>Opening QTY</th>
                <th class='headers'>Closing QTY</th>
                <th class='headers'>Corrupted QTY</th>
                <th class='headers'>Date In</th>
                <th class='headers'>Date Out</th>
                <th class='headers'>Remarks</th>
                <th class='headers'>NTA SAM Reference No.</th>
                <th class='headers' colspan="2">Action to take</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="bResults"></tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#togglething').click(function(){
if ( $( ".table1" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
    $( ".table1" ).slideDown( "slow" );
} else {
    $( ".table1" ).hide();
}
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-angle-up fa-angle-down')
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.table1 {
display:none;
position:relative;
}
table thead th .text {
  position:relative;
}
#table-wrapper {
  overflow:auto;  
}
#scrolling{
  overflow:auto;
}
```

So I am following jquery documentation on `slideDown()` but somehow, it does not slide down slowly and neither does it hide after that. I tried using `$(document).ready` but it does not seem to be the issue either which puzzles me. Does my position in css inteferes with the hide effect or slideDown effect?
Is there some alternative ways to make this work or a solution to enable the effects? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not altogether sure why yours is not working, however if you wrap your table in a div and slidedown / hide that it works as expected. eg:

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="toggling" id="togglething"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
<div id="scrolling"> 
        <!--<div id="loading"></div>-->
        <div class="slide-container">
    <table id="results" class="table1" cellspacing="10px">
            <thead>
        <tr class = "spacing">
                <th class='headers'>Index No</th>
                <th class='headers'>SAM ID</th>
                <th class='headers'>Item Description</th>
                <th class='headers'>Type</th>
                <th class='headers'>Inventory Status</th>
                <th class='headers'>Issued QTY</th>
                <th class='headers'>Opening QTY</th>
                <th class='headers'>Closing QTY</th>
                <th class='headers'>Corrupted QTY</th>
                <th class='headers'>Date In</th>
                <th class='headers'>Date Out</th>
                <th class='headers'>Remarks</th>
                <th class='headers'>NTA SAM Reference No.</th>
                <th class='headers' colspan="2">Action to take</th>
              </tr>
      </thead>
            <tbody id="bResults">
      </tbody>
          </table>
  </div>
      </div>
```

JS:

```
$('#togglething').click(function(){
if ( $( ".slide-container" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {

    $( ".slide-container" ).slideDown( 'slow' );
} else {
    $( ".slide-container" ).hide();
}
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-angle-up fa-angle-down')
});
```

CSS:

```
.slide-container {
    display: none;
}
.table1 {
    position: relative;
}
table thead th .text {
    position: relative;
}
#table-wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
}
#scrolling {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This (somewhat simplified) jQuery code works. Now you can modify it to do what you want.

I have no idea why the the `.slideUp()` reacts so sluggish, it is something jQuery.

```js
$('#togglething').click(function(){
 if ( $( ".table1" ).is( ":visible" ) ) { $( ".table1" ).slideUp()  ; }
 else                                   { $( ".table1" ).slideDown(); }

    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-angle-up fa-angle-down')
});
```

```css
.table1 {
display:none;
position:relative;
}
table thead th .text {
  position:relative;
}
#table-wrapper {
  overflow:auto;  
}
#scrolling{
  overflow:auto;
}  
done */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="toggling" id="togglething"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
<div id="scrolling">
    <table id="results" class="table1" cellspacing=10px>
        <thead>
            <tr class = "spacing">
                <th class='headers'>Index No</th>
                <th class='headers'>SAM ID</th>
                <th class='headers'>Item Description</th>
                <th class='headers'>Type</th>
                <th class='headers'>Inventory Status</th>
                <th class='headers'>Issued QTY</th>
                <th class='headers'>Opening QTY</th>
                <th class='headers'>Closing QTY</th>
                <th class='headers'>Corrupted QTY</th>
                <th class='headers'>Date In</th>
                <th class='headers'>Date Out</th>
                <th class='headers'>Remarks</th>
                <th class='headers'>NTA SAM Reference No.</th>
                <th class='headers' colspan="2">Action to take</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="bResults"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Should I use css in transition instead of jquery? Can't seem to think of anything else that would help it out

Comment: Indeed, personally I would use a 'checkbox toggle trick' with some animation/transition to solve the sliding, just as easy to understand and no jQuery/JS required. Simply Google for it or search Codepen. Plenty examples available.

Answer (score 0):

Setting your .table1 to display:block seems to help with the sliding.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="toggling" id="togglething"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>

<table id="results" class="table1" cellspacing="10px" style="display:none; border:1px solid #000">
  <thead>
    <tr class = "spacing">
      <th class='headers'>Index No</th>
      <th class='headers'>SAM ID</th>
      <th class='headers'>Item Description</th>
      <th class='headers'>Type</th>
      <th class='headers'>Inventory Status</th>
      <th class='headers'>Issued QTY</th>
      <th class='headers'>Opening QTY</th>
      <th class='headers'>Closing QTY</th>
      <th class='headers'>Corrupted QTY</th>
      <th class='headers'>Date In</th>
      <th class='headers'>Date Out</th>
      <th class='headers'>Remarks</th>
      <th class='headers'>NTA SAM Reference No.</th>
      <th class='headers' colspan="2">Action to take</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="bResults">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$( "#togglething" ).click(function() {
  $( "#results" ).slideToggle( "slow");
});
```

CSS:

```
.table1 {display:block;}
```

And a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/La2sfjnx/)